# Constructing piecewise quadratic polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods

The question asks to construct a piecewise quadratic polynomial defined on the interval $\mathbb{R}$ of the form
$$
B_0=
\begin{cases}
p(x)=x^2,\qquad\qquad\quad\; 0\leq x<1,\\
q(x)=ax^2+bx+c,\quad\, 1\leq x<2,\\
r(x)=(3-x)^2,\qquad\quad 2\leq x<3,\\
0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I need to find the coefficients for $q(x)$. However, I'm having trouble with figuring out which method to use. We're dealing with uniform quadratic B-splines. Would I need to use the Gram-Schmidt method?

Thanks.

Comment: **Hint** B-splines have the property that they are continuous. Higher order splines have continuity of derivatives, how many depends on the order of the approximation.

Comment: Do you mean I would have to derive q(x)?

Comment: Possibly, it depends on the way that they are defined. You need to have $p(1) = q(1)$ and $q(2)=r(2)$ for continuity. Do these uniquely describe $q(x)$ or is derivative information needed?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not sure what you mean by your last statement. The only other information given is to determine a,b,c so that $B_0$ is in $C^1$(ℝ).

Comment: The two conditions that I give don't uniquely determine $q(x)$. You also require that $p'(1)=q'(1)$ and $q'(2)=r'(2)$. This is also needed for it to be in $C^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comments above, you require the spline to satisfy $p(1)=q(1)$, $q(2)=r(2)$ for function continuity and $p'(1)=q'(1)$ and $q'(2)=r'(2)$ for derivative continuity.

The result of this is an overdetermined linear system, which has a unique solution.